# adding a codepen pen to wordpress as a landing page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, codepen

I don't have much experience with web development but I'm learning along the way.

I created a new website on wordpress, and I found a nifty lil codepen pen that I want to add as a landing page before the actual website.

```
`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZobXy`
```

I've found plugins that let me create landing pages and such, and I've managed to add the HTML part of it as a shortcode but finding it hard to add the css and js, and I'm inexperienced as far as manually adding the code; unless someone has an answer to that or links to tutorials.

Long story short, I want to add that 'pen' as a landing page before my actual website. It's a sushi/switch. Once you switch it, I want it to redirect to my page's actual homepage.

Is this possible/realistic?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you have a child theme. If not, then create one following this [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/) or any other you find on Google

Then you need 3 steps:

**Create a PHP file in the child theme folder with this on top:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Landing Page
 */
 ?>
 Copy paste the HTML block of code pen here as you see it
```

Create a new Wordpress page with empty content and choose on the right sidebar the template you just created.

**Create a js file in the child theme folder:**

Add here the code from the Javascript section of codepen as you see it. Then go to the `functions.php` file of your child them and add the following:

```
function my_landing_page_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('myCustomLandingScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my_js_file_name.js',array('jquery'),1.0, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_landing_page_scripts');
```

**Finally, open `styles.css` file of your child theme:**
And copy paste here anything you see on CSS section of the code pen.

That's it... Now, the Landing Page will be fully functional.